# How to fetch data from database with 3 parameters Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm still new to this laravel, for now I'm facing a trouble for fetching data from the database. What i want to get is when there are only one data available, the second parameters won't be executed, but if there are some data available on the second parameters, then all the data from first parameter and the second parameter will be called.

```
    $detail = Barang_Keluar_Detail::findOrFail($id); //15
    $cariid = $detail->pluck('barang_keluar_id');
    $instansiquery = Barang_Keluar::where('id',$cariid)->first(); //21
    $instansiid = $instansiquery->pluck('instansi_id');
    $tanggal = $instansiquery->pluck('tanggal')->first();//2019-12-31
```

and the parameter are here

```
    $cariinstasama = Barang_Keluar::where('id', $cariid)
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use($instansiid, $tanggal) {
            $query->where('tanggal', "'$tanggal'")
            ->where('instansi_id', $instansiid);
        });
```

Please any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear actually or else you'd have definitely got an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laravel query builder provides elegant way to put conditional clause using `when()` . You can put conditional clause on your query like this:

```
$cariinstasama = Barang_Keluar::where('id', $cariid)
    ->when($instansiid, function ($query, $instansiid) {
        return $query->where('instansi_id', $instansiid);
    })
    ->when($tanggal, function ($query, $tanggal) {
        return $query->where('tanggal', $tanggal);
    })->get();
```

For more info see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses

Answer (score 3):

You can try this as well.

```
$cariinstasama = Barang_Keluar::where('id', $cariid);

if($instansiid !== null)
{
   $cariinstasama->where('instansi_id', $instansiid); 
}

if($tanggal !== null) 
{
   $cariinstasama->where('instansi_id', $instansiid);
}

$result = $cariinstasama->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what exactly you want.

Are you applying more than one parameter on the query if the first parameter result gives you more than one row in the database? If yes check out my approach :

```
$query = new Model(); // the model you want to query
if($query->where('col1', $param1)->count() > 1) // checks if the query from the 1st parameter produces more than one row in the database
     $query = $query->where( // if yes apply more parameters to the query
        [
           ['col1', $param1],
           ['col2', $param2]
        ]
     );
else
    $query = $query->where('col1', $param1);
$results = $query->get();
```

Hope it helps....